# how to call stored procedure in php

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures

i have created store procedure like this

```
delimiter //
create procedure tom()
begin
select name from table where id = 1 
end
//
```

i am calling this store procedure in php like this

```
if($connection){
echo "connected";
$res = R::exec('call tom');
    var_dump($res);
}
```

the query is executing but i am not able to fetch the value 
for example: expected output  for this  is `tom` (name in the table where id=1) 
             but i am getting `int(1)`
that means query is executing but i am not able to fetch the value, how to do it?

Comment: here i have used R::exec because i am using redbean(ORM)

Comment: $res just gives the boolean value whether the query is executed or not. I don't know about readbean orm but in php mysqli you do it with $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); here $row gives you an associative array

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$mysqli->multi_query("CALL YOURPROCEDURE()");


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `R::exec` just executes a query. You have to use this to get multidimensional array. Here is the link for this. [redbean orm queries](http://www.redbeanphp.com/queries)

```
R::getAll( 'call tom' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detail discussion about how write and execute stored procedures in PHP.

Try [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php). It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a Stored Procedure from PHP

```
$dbms = 'mysql';

//Replace the below connection parameters to fit your environment

$host = '192.168.1.8'; // give host IP
$db = 'myDB';          // give your db name here
$user = 'myUser';      // give the username here to connect
$pass = 'myPass';      // give the password for the user
$dsn = "$dbms:host=$host;dbname=$db";

$cn=new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$res=$cn->exec('call tom');
print_r($res);
```

For more information, visit [How to write and call stored procedures in PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Well its quite simple. I think you are looking forward to know how to call a store procedure using readbeanphp & retrieve the result of store procedure.

its simple. Try this

```
$response    = R::getCol("CALL procesedure() ");
print_r($response);
```

It will return the result.